# Autolayout Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i have a big Problem with Autolayout....

have a View Controller , in this i have on top a View, then under the View a Table View, 
inside the Table View is a View ... and in this View are views......

auto layout ar not working... it works on iphone... but on the Preview from the ipad.... ist not ok...

on the Screenshot you see what i mean ..

Thanks for help...

[My Test Projekt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3798714/autolayout.zip)

[image]

Comment: I am not able to understand the problem , Can you elaborate?